# Jquery function with 2 arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading this very interesting article about knockoutJs ( http://wildermuth.com/2011/11/20/Using_MVVM_on_the_Web_with_KnockoutJS )

And I came across this jquery call:

```
        $.each(response.results, function (x, game) {
          theViewModel.games.push(new gameModel()
          .id(game.Id)
          .name(game.Name)
          .releaseDate(game.ReleaseDate)
          .price(game.Price)
          .imageUrl(game.ImageUrl)
          .genre(game.Genre));
        });
```

what I don' t understand is the function (x, game), the x is the index isn' t ?, how about the 'game' argument, where is it coming from ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/ --- **ALWAYS** consult to documentation before you ask a question

Comment: exactly, I read it twice, now I just understand :), sorry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback you supply to `$.each` will be called once for eaach result in `response.results`. When it calls the callback it will pas in the index and the result.

For example, it does this (illustrative example)

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
    yourCallback(i, response.results[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sohnee, I didn' t see by this angle, thanks for your answer